# error while trying to get table from dbase

Tags: php, mysql

I have dbase named "promotion_map".:
[map of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtOij.png)

I'm trying to fetch data form this db but this not working while executing this:

`$tpl->assign('prom_maps', $prom_maps->getPromotionMap());`

function `getPromotionMap()` is defined in other php file:

```
<?php
require_once("../common/qDB3.class.php");

class PromotionMap extends QDB3{
    function PromotionMap($DB){
        $this->tableName = "promotion_map";
        $this->indexField = "id";
        $this->d = array(
            "id"=>"",
            "promotion_id"=>"",
            "type"=>"",
            "period"=>"",
            "name"=>"",
            "duration"=>"",
            "fee"=>"",
        );
        $this->QDB3($DB);
    }

    function getPromotionMap() {
        return $this->DB->getAssoc("SELECT * FROM `{$this->tableName}`");
    }

    function getPromotionMap($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        return $this->DB->getRow("SELECT * FROM `{$this->tableName}` WHERE `id` = ?", [$id]);
    }

};
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I expecting to get table `"promotion_map"` from table.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Please read: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display), then you should have seen an error like: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getPromotionMap() ...`

Answer (score 0):

The PromotionMap class contains a definition of the getPromotionMap() method twice, which is against PHP rules.

you can rename the second method like below

```
function getPromotionMapById($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        return $this->DB->getRow("SELECT * FROM `{$this->tableName}` WHERE `id` = ?", [$id]);
}
```

so that you can use first method getPromotionMap() to fetch data form db